# Scalacheck is ignoring the provided generators

Tags: scala, sbt, scalacheck

I'm trying to implement a simple property check but Scalacheck is ignoring my generators. What I'm doing wrong here?

```
object AlgorithmTest extends Properties("Algorithm") {
  property("Test") = forAll (Gen.choose(0,10)) (n => n>=0 & n<10)
}
```

and this is the result in SBT

```
[info] ! Algorithm.Test: Falsified after 12 passed tests. [info] >
ARG_0: -1 [error] Failed: : Total 1, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 0,
Skipped 0
```

Comment: The issue has now been fixed (for built-in generators) via the use of `suchThat` postconditions - see https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/issues/8

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the Shrink instance which is passed to the `forAll` method is not using the generator when searching for smaller counter-examples. If you change your property to:

```
property("Test") = Prop.forAllNoShrink(Gen.choose(1, 10)) (n => n >= 0 && n < 10)
```

Then it should properly fail with:

```
[info] ! Algorithm.Test: Falsified after 7 passed tests.
[info] > ARG_0: 10
[error] Failed: : Total 1, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 0, Skipped 0
```

One way to visualize the Shrink values is to use the `Prop.collect` method:

```
property("Test") = Prop.forAll(Gen.choose(1, 10)) { n =>
  Prop.collect(n) { n >= 0 && n < 10 }
}
```

Then the collected values look like:

```
[info] ! Algorithm.Test: Falsified after 40 passed tests.
[info] > ARG_0: -1
[info] > Collected test data: 
[info] 17% 3
[info] 17% 1
[info] 15% 6
[info] 12% 9
[info] 10% 2
[info] 10% 5
[info] 7% 4
[info] 7% 8
[info] 2% -1
[info] 2% 7
```

Where you can see that -1 has been used during the shrinking process.

Comment: But this is not the documented behaviour. If I use a generator between 1 and 10 all the values must be in the range [1,10[ . Never should appear a -1

Comment: @ancechu The `-1` appears _after_ the test failed, as ScalaCheck tries to find simpler input that fails the test -- that's the "shrinking". That phase doesn't respect the generation process -- whether that's a bug or an intrinsic limitation, I don't know.

Comment: I should have searched yesterday but this issue is actually discussed [here](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/issues/18)

Comment: The issue has now been fixed (for built-in generators) via the use of `suchThat` postconditions - see https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/issues/8